# Android CountDownTimer crash

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm using for first time the CountDownTimer but, not working. Application crashes with this:

```
if(Game1.ifWorking == false) {
        new CountDownTimer (30000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Game1.ifWorking = false;
                Game1.points = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Game1.ifWorking = true;
                crono.setText("Test" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

        }.start();
    }
```

Variable:

```
private static boolean ifWorking;
```

What is the problem?

EDIT:

LogCat: http://i.gyazo.com/b20c01f75d173edf3ee1a5a8569423ab.png

Comment: Post the `logcat` please.

Comment: Post edited with image

Comment: see the line 47. I think `crono` not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View `crono` is `null`. Initialise your view and then call `setText`: `crono.setText("Test" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Do This tell me the error
If app is just on your own local device, you can use LogCat. Even if the device wasn't connected to a host machine when the crash occurred, connecting the device and issuing an adb logcat command will download the entire logcat history (at least to the extent that it is buffered which is usually a lot of log data, it's just not infinite).While i check for this CountDownTimer func.

TRY this

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.lang.*;

public class BooleanDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 Boolean objects b1, b2
      Boolean b1, b2;

      // create a boolean primitive res
      boolean res;

      // assign values to b1, b2
      b1 = new Boolean(true);
      b2 = new Boolean(false);

      // assign the result of equals method on b1, b2 to res
      res = b1.equals(b2);

      String str = "b1:" +b1+ " and b2:" +b2+ " are equal is " + res;

      // print res value
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}
Let us compile and run the above program, this will produce the following result:

b1:true and b2:false are equal is false
```

Comment: please try .equals() instead of ==

Comment: "Cannot invoke .equals(boolean)"

Comment: oh i thought u havent pasted whole code but next time please see logcat  it gives u exact error

Comment: just always check the line number and if u dont get error on that line see what would have caused an error in that line

Comment: I'm sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: we are here to help.and it is difficult to see these small mistake in a large code. enjoy